# Trigger Text Import Wizard in Excel based on file extension

Tags: microsoft-excel, fixed-width

We occasionally receive files with fixed-width fields. I have some users who need to open these in Excel. They mostly know how to use the Excel Text Import Wizard for this situation, but they sometimes have trouble remembering how to start the wizard. I'd like to make this easier for them by altering the file extension of the received file.

Is there a file extension that will trigger the Text Import Wizard to open automatically without modifying the default "Open With" settings in Windows?

I've tried *.csv, *.dat, and *.txt, and they don't work for me here. The users need to be able to just double-click on the file and have Excel open (so *.txt and *.dat fail) with the Text Import Wizard (*.csv doesn't trigger the wizard).

Similar (but the same as) this question:
[Automate Excel Text Import Wizard?](https://superuser.com/questions/153211/automate-excel-text-import-wizard)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Also, do the files arrive in the same place each time? How are they received? Email? FTP?

Comment: Excel 2016, likely updating to 2019 Pro Plus (not 365) in the next year
. Typically received via email, but I can handle getting the extension changed.

Comment: Have you considered writing an extension to the Outlook ribbon such that the attachment context menu includes an "Open with Excel" option? You could create the Excel application object in the VBA in Outlook and feed it the file from the email, instructing it to open with the import wizard.

Comment: I never said we use Outlook for email ;)

Comment: You didn't. But are they? Next you'll be telling me they're using Excel 2016 on Ubuntu. :) Anyway, short of changing the file association in Windows, which would make this need a Windows tag, not Excel, I don't believe there's any way of making this happen short of scripting it in VBA, vbscript or, I guess, bash/dos/ps.

Comment: No. We have a G Suite domain, but still use Office for documents.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn,,, if this is `files with fixed-width fields` the issue only,, I would like to suggest use `DATA`  then `Get External Data`,, and use `From text` is actually is Text file.